How to tee output from a command so only the last 1000 lines are saved in powershell
How to tee output from a command/App so only the last 1000 lines are saved in a file with Powershell but everything else is shown in the terminal

You could write your own Tee-Last function - use a Queue to buffer the input items, then write the results to file at the end:
function Tee-Last {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [psobject]$InputObject,

    [ValidateRange(1, 2147483647)]
    [int]$Count = $(0),

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$LiteralPath,

    [switch]$Append
  )

  begin {
    $isBounded = $Count -gt 0
    if ($isBounded) {
      $queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new($Count)
    }
    else {
      $queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new()
    }
  }

  process {
    if ($isBounded -and $queue.Count -eq $Count) {
      # if the queue is full, evict the oldest item
      $null = $queue.Dequeue()
    }

    $queue.Enqueue($InputObject)

    # output as-is
    Write-Output $InputObject -NoEnumerate
  }

  end {
    if ($queue.Count) {
      # write the buffered items to file
      $contentArgs = @{ LiteralPath = $LiteralPath }
      if ($Append) {
        $queue |Add-Content @contentArgs
      }
      else {
        $queue |Set-Content @contentArgs
      }
    }
  }
}

Then use it like this:
1..1000 |Tee-Last -LiteralPath .\output.txt -Count 10

You'll see that while all integers 1 through 1000 is printed on the screen, the file only contains 991 through 1000

$results = 'C:\path\to\App.exe'
$results | select -Last 10 | Out-File 'C:\path\to\LogFile.log'
Write-Output $results


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

I think the problem with this code is that output is first written to the terminal after the app has finished and $results have to hold all output which can be huge
